# How can I execute code from the Release / Release All buttons in the Release AR Documents screen

Tags: acumatica

I've got a customization to the Invoice & Memo screen where I execute some custom code (web service calls) when the Release action is activated.  This works fine - I knew how to replace the PXAction code and proceeded from there.  Now I want to use the Release AR Documents processing screen to do the same thing, but I'm having trouble understanding where / what to override, or where to place my code.

I see the ARDocumentRelease graph constructor with the SetProcessDelegate in the source code, but I'm not sure how to proceed - whether this is where I need to be looking or not.  I need to execute my code for each line being released, using the RefNbr in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the function

```
public static void ReleaseDoc(List<ARRegister> list, bool isMassProcess, List<Batch> externalPostList, ARMassProcessDelegate onsuccess)
```

under **ARDocumentRelease** businesss logic.

Comment: You can't override static functions using graph extensions. I highly recommend following the approach described by Alexander in the T300 training.

Comment: I actually found an example someone created where they overrode the base constructor call and rewrote the static releaseDoc method(s) (calling them 'conditionalReleaseDoc(...)'), and putting the conditional logic in the main method.  This works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's an static method, you can't override it. Also, you can't do like it's done in the T300, because you are in processing graph and you can't override the release button with your own. I was able to achieve it by passing callback for each AR document that have been processed.

You can call the `Initialize` method of the `ARDocumentRelease` graph to override the logic like you said. After you just have to call `ReleaseDoc` that uses a callback parameter instead of using the default one.

Here's the code that I came with:

```
public class ARDocumentRelease_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARDocumentRelease>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        ARSetup setup = Base.arsetup.Current;

        Base.ARDocumentList.SetProcessDelegate(
            delegate (List<BalancedARDocument> list)
            {
                List<ARRegister> newlist = new List<ARRegister>(list.Count);
                foreach (BalancedARDocument doc in list)
                {
                    newlist.Add(doc);
                }
                AddAdditionalLogicToRelease(newlist);
            }
        );
        Base.ARDocumentList.SetProcessCaption("Release");
        Base.ARDocumentList.SetProcessAllCaption("Release All");
    }

    public delegate void PostPorcessing(ARRegister ardoc, bool isAborted);


    private void AddAdditionalLogicToRelease(List<ARRegister> newlist)
    {
        ARDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(newlist, true, null, delegate(ARRegister ardoc, bool isAborted) {
            //Add your logic to handle each document
            //Test to check if it was not aborted
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you must always call static methods from within long running process and create necessary objects there.

Processing delegate logic is implemented as long running process which creates worker thread to execute the processing logic.

You have AddAdditionalLogicToRelease() method which requires object instance in order to call and will fail during thread context switches and hence the issue. So, you must have create object instance inside the thread context and then call instance method.

In general, method that gets called from long running processes are declared static and required objects/graphs are created inside this static method to do some work.  See below example how to properly override ARDocumentRelease graph for this purpose:

```
public class ARDocumentRelease_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARDocumentRelease>
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {

        Base.ARDocumentList.SetProcessDelegate(
            delegate (List<BalancedARDocument> list)
            {
                List<ARRegister> newlist = new List<ARRegister>(list.Count);
                foreach (BalancedARDocument doc in list)
                {
                    newlist.Add(doc);
                }



                // use override that allows to specify onsuccess routine
                ARDocumentRelease.ReleaseDoc(newlist, true, null, (ardoc, isAborted) =>
                {
                    //Custom code here, such as create your GL
                });
            }
        );

    }
}
```